# Yii encoding whole page lost format encoding after submitting form

Tags: php, forms, firefox, yii, encoding

I have a website with some form (2-step registration) and after I submit the form with some errors (i.e. missing password or too short username) the page reload and "lost" information about encoding  so the page looks very bad:

[image]
link to the website where this form is: 
http://portalpracy24.pl/pracodawca/zarejestruj

Can't find the problem where is, charset=utf-8 is present all the time :/ Anyone can help?

This problem is only in Firefox :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the problem,

Just addedd 2 line to htaccess and works great:

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
AddCharset UTF-8 .php